# how to mark records that are read in mssql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a system that sends some information by SMS daily to our customers. as the procedure of sending SMS can take a while this is done by multiple processes that each process sends a limited number of SMSs. when a Process reads a number of records of pohne nubers (lets say 1000 of them) to send sms. I want to mark these 1000 records that the other process wouldn't read these records too.

```
Select Top(1000) ID, Number from Phones where isactive = 1 and isverified = 1
```

I need some code that does something like this:

`update Phones, set ReadTime = getdate() where` (selected above)

now I want to update the column `ReadTime` of these records to `getdate()` to make sure that other schduled processes won't read them again (the reason i'm setting a datetime flag instead of a Bit flag is that some SMS sending might fail and this way I can understand which ones are read long ago but not updated the sent time)

marking them after sending the sms (that should be done anyway to write sent time) wouldn't help as the the scheduled taks that will process the sending SMSs will read all 1000 records at once and there might be records that are read by other processes but not flaged yet (as the SMS hasn't been sent yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Phones
SET ReadTime = GetDate()
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Top 1000 ID
             FROM Phones
             WHERE IsActive = 1
                 AND IsVerified = 1
                 AND ReadTime Is Null -- you will want to exclude any records already updated
             ORDER BY ID)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88bd1/3)

Comment: how can this ensure that the chosen rows are the same as the rows you update ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk actually it does update the same records, if there is a filter added to include dates it does work as expected.

Comment: you are updating 1000 rows, but those 1000 rows are not nessasarily the same rows as the rows selected in the question. So as your query is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can select and output the rows in one go. This will ensure that the rows selected are the same as the rows updated, the chosen answer fails doing this.

```
;with a
as
(
select top 1000 readtime, id, number from @phones 
where isactive = 1 and isverified = 1 
and readtime is null
)
update a
set Readtime = getdate()
output deleted.ID, deleted.Number
```

Comment: this line `readtime < datediff(day, 0, getdate())` is going to cause all records to be updated again with a new `readtime`.

Comment: @bluefeet yes I misunderstood the part about the readtime, changed that part now.

Answer (score 1):

May you can add an extra column to the table which takes the id of the process ID.
Then you can call in each process:

```
UPDATE Phones
SET ReadTime = GetDate(),
ProcessId = "Process0001" --or whatever the process ID is
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Top 1000 ID FROM Phones WHERE IsActive = 1 AND IsVerified = 1
                 AND ProcessId IS NULL AND ReadTime IS NULL)
```

Then you call all records with your process ID. At the end you delete the process ID from the table.